# Compare two DATE and get Days in c#

Tags: c#

Count Number of days by comapaing two date, When you want to compare two date like due Date and return date of a book in library then you can get no of days in this manner

```
        int TotalDay;
        DateTime due = OldDate;

        int day = due.Day;
        int nday = DateTime.Now.Day;
        int mnt = due.Month;
        int nmnt = DateTime.Now.Month;
        int yr = due.Year;
        int nyr = DateTime.Now.Year;
        if (nyr <= yr)
        {
            if (nmnt <= mnt)
            {
                if (nday > day)
                {
                    TotalDay = nday - day;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TotalDay = nday - day;
                m = nmnt - mnt;
                TotalDay = d + (m * 30);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TotalDay = nday - day;
            m = nmnt - mnt;
            TotalDay  = d + (m * 30);
            int y = nyr - yr;
            TotalDay  = d + (y * 365);
        }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
TimeSpan ts = dateTime1 - dateTime2;
```

`ts.TotalDays` will give you the difference in number of days.

In your case `due` is the due date and `DateTime.Now` is the current date. You may use:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - due;
```

or use the [`TimeSpan.TotalDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) property:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(due);

double NumberOfDays = ts.TotalDays;
```

Comment: Dont you think it should be `due - DateTime.Now` because Now will be smaller than duedate.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, sure the OP can use the ABS value in that case, but I think, one needs to check the difference in days where it is overdue, but again, it depends and can easily be changed

Comment: @Habib Your answer will not compile. You need to cast `ts.TotalDays` as an `int` because it returns a `double`, and you have declared `NumberOfDays` as an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use `TimeSpan` as shown in other answers - but you need to be careful about the time of day. Are you actually trying to think of these as *dates* or as dates with times? What about time zones? Are you using "local" `DateTime` values for both?

While `DateTime` can handle all of this, it leaves things unclear. I'd personally use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) (which shouldn't surprise anyone as it's my own library...)

```
LocalDate startDate = ...;
LocalDate endDate = ...;

long days = Period.Between(startDate, endDate, PeriodUnits.Days).Days;
```

Note that finding "today's date" requires knowing the appropriate time zone, too. (`DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Today` assume the system time zone where your code is running, but that may or may not be what you want.)

Answer (score 2):

You need `TimeSpan`

```
Timespan t = ReturnDateTime - DateTime.Now;
```

Then use

```
t.Days
```

for calculating how many days are left.